# MaxReceivedMessageSize error in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security

As Im new to WCF, please help me out. I am getting this error. I have searched on internet for this problem and I have got many solution, but when I applied those solutions. some new problems I am facing. So please provide me a valid solution.

The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Service Web.config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WcfServiceZone_Store.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceZone_Store.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client Web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:50274/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

please tell me, on which side I need to make changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the change on both sides - server and client - but you need to make it to the **appropriate** binding - the one your service (and client) are actually using!

So in your case, on your server-side, the service is configured to use `wsHttpBinding`:

```
<service name="WcfServiceZone_Store.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
   <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceZone_Store.IService1">
                                 *************
```

but you've defined the higher values on the `basicHttpBinding` ..... that won't work, of course!

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    ****************   this doesn't match with the defined binding on your endpoint!
```

And you're also not referencing the new binding configuration you've defined - you need to **TELL** WCF to actually use those new binding values!

So you need to do this on the server:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingWithMaxSizeIncreased" 
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="WcfServiceZone_Store.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="wsHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="BindingWithMaxSizeIncreased"  -- use those new values!
        contract="WcfServiceZone_Store.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Same thing on the client-side:

- define the binding parameters for the **correct** binding (`wsHttpBinding` - not `basicHttpBinding`)
- add a reference to the `bindingConfiguration` to the `<endpoint>` so that those values will actually be used

Comment: `wsHttpBinding` has no `maxBufferSize` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For **customBinding** add **httpTransport** with these values:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="QueryDocumentWSPortBinding">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />

              <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                            keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                            realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                            useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
            </binding>
            ....
```